# A Beautiful Integral: $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log(\sin x)\log(\cos x)\,dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I have to find the value of
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\log(\cos(x))\log(\sin(x))dx$$

in terms of $\pi$ and $\log(2)$. Any hint?

Comment: A parenthesis is missing in your integral, so it is not clear what the integrating function should be. Is this question supposed to be a challenge?

Comment: Yes it should be a challenge and the question is edited

Comment: It is an interesting problem, but you should show your attempts to solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By Feynman's trick/differentiation under the integral sign and Euler's beta function:
$$I=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log(\sin x)\log(\cos x)\,dx = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial a\,\partial b}\left.\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1+a}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1+b}{2}\right)}{2\,\Gamma(\frac{a+b+2}{2})}\right|_{(a,b)=(0,0)}\tag{1}$$
Since $\Gamma'(x) = \psi(x)\,\Gamma(x)$, we have:
$$ I = \lim_{(a,b)\to (0,0)}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1+a}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{1+b}{2}\right)}{8\,\Gamma(\frac{a+b+2}{2})}\left[\psi\left(\frac{1+a}{2}\right)\psi\left(\frac{1+b}{2}\right)+\ldots-\psi'\left(\frac{a+b+2}{2}\right)\right]\tag{2}$$
and by exploiting:
$$ \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi},\qquad \psi(1)=-\gamma,\qquad \psi'(1)=\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6} \tag{3}$$
we get:

> $$ I = -\frac{\pi^3}{48}-\frac{\pi\log 2}{4}\left[\gamma+\psi\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right] =\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}\log^2 2-\frac{\pi^3}{48}}.\tag{4}$$

Comment: Just curious did you look up the trick or did you just know how to do it?

Comment: @Wolfy: it is a well-known trick to deal with logarithmic integrals, I used it many times here on MSE.